# Styling by SLD according to multiple field

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

I have a shapefile which have two fields say it is "level" and "type".

Now we want to style the map according to the value of the `level` and `type` fields.

Generally we use something rule based symbol to style the layer like this:

```
rule
  level=1
    style....
  level=2
    style...
```

However once there are multiple fields to be filtered it may change to this:

```
rule
  level=1 and type=1
    style....
  level=1 and type=2
    style...
  level=2 and type=1
    style...
  level=2 and type=2
    style...
  level=3 and type=1
    style...
```

It seems like we have to specify all the possibility of the composition of different field. Think about if there are 10+ distinct values of each field, there will be 10*10*10 kinds of rules which will be a hard job.

How do you handle this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the tranformation functions to get a more compact style:

- http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/downloads/releases/2.8.x-ld/doc/styling/sld-tipstricks/transformation-func.html
- http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/css/examples/transformation.html

Mind, you'll break GetLegendGraphics by using these functions, but with that many combinations you probably don't care.

Answer (score 1):

CSS styling is a good way to simplify your SLD (you write CSS and it generates the XML for SLD). Could work: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/index.html